# Union of select queries with cte

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I m trying to union two select queries which uses cte’s.

Ex:

Query1:

```
With cte1 as
(Select assignment_number 
From per_all_assignments_f)

Select cte1.assignment_number
From per_all_Assignments_f
Where assignment_status = ‘ACTIVE’


Query2:
With cte2 as
(Select assignment_number 
From per_all_assignments_f)

Select cte2.assignment_number
From per_all_assignments_f
Where assignment_status = ‘INACTIVE’
```

Now, I want to union query1 and query2. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: **(1)** Which of the two DBMS are you using, MySQL or Oracle? **(2)** You've completely messed up your examples. You are only selecting `assignment_number` in the CTEs, but in your query you are not selecting from the CTEs, but from the original tables with another column (`assignment_status`). You may want to correct this. Are the two CTEs identical?

Comment: Sorry zaynul. I m new to oracle sql and It is my first try here. However got my answer. Thanks for that searle. I ll try to be more specific from next time.

Comment: With cte1 as
(
    SELECT assignment_number,
           assignment_status
    FROM   per_all_assignments_f
),
cte2 as
(
    SELECT assignment_number,
           assignement_status
    FROM   per_all_assignments_f
)
SELECT  assignment_number
FROM    cte1
WHERE   assignment_status = ‘ACTIVE’
UNION -- OR UNION ALL   
SELECT  cte2.assignment_number
FROM    per_all_assignments_f
WHERE   assignment_status = ‘INACTIVE’


This is working. Now I want to get the result order by the assignment_number. In this case how to achieve it? Can you please help.

Comment: If you want to sort rows, add an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

What's the purpose of doing it that way? Isn't it just

```
select assignment_number
from per_all_assignments_f
where assignment_status in ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')
```

Comment: Whilst this certainly a better query, I suspect the OP's query is simplified for brevity

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
With cte1 as
(Select assignment_number ,assignment_status
From per_all_assignments_f
)
,
cte2 as
(Select assignment_number ,assignment_status
From per_all_assignments_f)
Select cte1.assignment_number
From cte1
Where assignment_status = 'ACTIVE'
union 
Select cte2.assignment_number
From cte2
Where assignment_status = 'INACTIVE'
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul, in the actual select queries, I m using multiple tables and joins. Just to simplify my scenario, I have used the above query as an example

Comment: @maxsamuel there is no problem to use multiple tables and join

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You have to comma separate the CTEs and then select from then

```
With cte1 as
(
    SELECT assignment_number,
           assignment_status
    FROM   per_all_assignments_f
),
cte2 as
(
    SELECT assignment_number,
           assignement_status
    FROM   per_all_assignments_f
)
SELECT  assignment_number
FROM    cte1
WHERE   assignment_status = ‘ACTIVE’
UNION -- OR UNION ALL   
SELECT  assignment_number
FROM    per_all_assignments_f
WHERE   assignment_status = ‘INACTIVE’
ORDER BY assignment_number
```

Comment: Thank you Searle. It is working. I just have one more issue on the above query. I want to give order by assignment_number. Can u help me?